# Vigenere cipher runs into infinite loop

Tags: c, encryption, vigenere

I had originally a Caesar's cypher code, which looked like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        printf("Insira a frase:\n");
        char frase [256];
        //strcpy(frase, argv[1]);
        scanf("%s", frase);
        int size = (int)strlen(frase);
        printf("Insira o tamanho da divergência: \n");
        int diff = 0;
        scanf("%i", &diff);
        char fraseout [size+1];
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<=size-1; i++)
        {
                int val = (int)frase[i];
                if (val + diff > 126)
                {
                        while (val + diff >126)
                        {
                                val = 31+diff-(126-val);
                        }
                }
                else if (val + diff < 32)
                {
                        while (val + diff < 32)
                        {
                                val = 127 + diff+(val-32);
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        val +=diff;
                }
                fraseout [i] = (char)val;
        }
        fraseout[size] = '\0';
        printf("\"%s\" -> \"%s\"\n", frase, fraseout);
        return 0;
}
```

I then decided to turn it into a Vinegere's cypher code, where the codifying number for each character is given by a password and iterates over the length of the word. So, if my word is "abcde" and my password is "zx" the pair (char, diff) would be (a,z)(b,x)(c,z)(d,x)... The code looks as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
        /* code */
        char senha [256];
        if (argv[1] != NULL)
        {
                strcpy(senha, argv[1]);
        }
        char frase [256];
        printf("Insira a frase: \n");
        scanf("%s", frase);
        int sizeS = (int)strlen(senha);
        int sizeF = (int)strlen(frase);
        char fraseout [sizeF+1];
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i=0; i<=sizeF-1; i++)
        {
                if(j>sizeS)
                {
                        j=0;
                }
                int valF = (int)frase[i];
                int valS = (int)senha[i];
                printf(" F = %c = %i \n S = %c = %i\n", frase[i], valF, senha[i], valS);
                if (valF+valS > 126)
                {
                        while (valF+valS >126)
                        {
                                printf("ValF = %i\n", valF);
                                printf("ValS = %i\n", valS);
                                valF = 31 + valS-(valF-126);
                                printf("NewV = %i\n", valF);
                        }
                }
                else if (valF+valS < 32)
                {
                        while (valF+valS<32)
                        {
                                valF = 127 + valS+(valF-32);
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        valF += valS;
                }
                printf("OUT = %i = %c\n",valF, (char)valF);
                printf("_________________________________\n");
                fraseout[i] = (char)valF;
                j++;
        }
        fraseout[sizeF] = '\0';
        printf("\"%s\" -> \"%s\"\n", frase, fraseout);
        return 0;
}
```

For some reason however this code just enters in an infinite loop on the firt `while()` statement and I don't get why. How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you inserted some `printf()` statements into the affected loop.  What do they print?

Comment: NewV = 176
ValF = 176
ValS = 116
NewV = 97
ValF = 97
ValS = 116
NewV = 176
ValF = 176
ValS = 116
NewV = 97
ValF = 97
ValS = 116
NewV = 176
ValF = 176
ValS = 116
NewV = 97
ValF = 97
ValS = 116

and on and on and on forever.

Comment: You're never using `j` for anything. Shouldn't it be `senha[j]` instead of `senha[i]`?

Comment: Just tried that, no results, still "NewV = 176
ValF = 176
ValS = 116
NewV = 97
ValF = 97
ValS = 116
NewV = 176
ValF = 176
ValS = 116
NewV = 97
ValF = 97
ValS = 116
NewV = 176
ValF = 176
ValS = 116
NewV = 97
ValF = 97
ValS = 116
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems I can see:

First, `senha[i]` should be `senha[j]`.

Second, `if (j > sizeS)` should be `if (j >= sizeS)`. Otherwise, you'll try to access `senha[sizeS]`, which contains the null terminator, not one of the characters in the string.

I think all that code for trying to deal with the addition of the characters going outside the printing range can be replaced with:

```
valF = 32 + ((valF - 32) + (valS - 32)) % (128-32);
```

Comment: Attempted that, output still the same broken loop: "ValF = 176
ValS = 116
NewV = 97
ValF = 97
ValS = 116
NewV = 176
ValF = 176
ValS = 116
NewV = 97
ValF = 97
ValS = 116
NewV = 176
ValF = 176
ValS = 116
NewV = 97
ValF = 97
ValS = 116
NewV = 176
ValF = 176
ValS = 116
"

Comment: I haven't tried to figure out what's wrong with the `while` loop. I've updated the answer with a simple formula that does it using modulus.

Comment: Why is it 128 and not 127 on the last subtraction?

Comment: Because modular arithmetic doesn't include the top value.

Comment: Oh, okay, I'll do my reading on modular arithmetic, thanks a lot for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
while (a + b > 126)
    a = 31 + b - (a-126);
```

is an infinite loop when:

```
a + b = 127  && a < 95    
a + b = 128  && a < 96    
etc.
```

In the case of `a + b = 127` and `a = 94` we get alternating values of `127` and `129` for `a + b`. For `a = 96` it alternates between `127` and `132`, and this second value only goes up as `a` goes down or `b` goes up.